# Hours changing their value on backend

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datetime

I am passing JS dateTime to backend with ajax(axios). This is what I have before post request 
`Sun Nov 04 2018 21:53:38 GMT+0500`
 and this is what I get on my backend
`2018-11-04T16:53:38.783Z`
As you can see hours have changed. Why is this happening?
Thanks

Comment: Well, its becouse you send it in GMT+5 and on the server you get it on UTC(+0)
you can decalre your timezone with 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php
this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely culprit by far is a different (or none at all) timezone setting.

Notice that you're sending "21:53 on plus five hours GMT":

```
Sun Nov 04 2018 21:53:38 GMT+0500
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and the server is interpreting as "16:53 Zulu":

```
2018-11-04T16:53:38.783Z
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And 16:53 Zulu is exactly 21:53+0500. But more than that, the server is not sending back you your own time, it's doing something in addition (see those 783 milliseconds?).

So, chances are that if you can't change the server settings, you'll have to convert back the date and time, or send your times from [the Zulu (not-)timezone](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/z).